# How can I write a function to return all the binary numbers with N digits, and in sorted order?

Tags: python

Each binary number should be represented as a tuple. When the function is called, the result should be a tuple containing 2^N binary numbers.

Ex. Binary(2)----> ((0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1))

I am trying to use a while loop to do this.

Just some advice on where I could begin would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), to get what you want

```
print [item for item in itertools.product([0, 1], repeat = 4)]
```

**Output**

```
[(0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 0, 0),
 (0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 1),
 (1, 0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1, 0),
 (1, 1, 1, 1)]
```

Change the `repeat` to the desired value.

**Edit:**
Performance comparison with `list` and comprehension.

```
print timeit.timeit("[item for item in itertools.product([0, 1], repeat = 4)]", number = 1000000)
print timeit.timeit("list(itertools.product([0, 1], repeat = 4))", number = 1000000)
```

List comprehension is slightly faster than `list`.

Comment: Unless I am missing something, why not just `print list(itertools.product([0,1], repeat = 4))`? `[item for item in x]` should always set off bells.

Comment: @sortfiend I just ran tests with `timeit`. It shows that comprehension is faster than `list`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need two loops -- an outer one to loop thru the values, and an inner one to process the binary digits for each value.

You can either loop thru the values as integers & convert them to binary -- or you can carry a "current value" in binary around the loop, copying & incrementing it.

Comment: I agree with this solution, as it answers the question using "while loop", which is what OP actually requested. Just to clarify, the main answer by ThomasW is the part "You can loop through the values (up to `2^n`) as integer, then convert it into its `n`-bit binary representation as tuple.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def binary(n):
    num_digits = len(bin(n).replace('0b',''))

    all_bin_numbers=()

    for i in range(n):
        bin_num=()
        for digit in str(bin(i)).replace('0b','').rjust(num_digits, '0'):
            bin_num += (int(digit),)
        all_bin_numbers += (bin_num,)

    return all_bin_numbers

print binary(2)
```

e: holy cow, that itertools answer.
e2: so it appears I didn't fully read the question, I was thinking you wanted all the binary numbers up to and including your specified n.

Answer (score 0):

```
from numpy import binary_repr
[map(int, binary_repr(i, N)) for i in range(2**N)]
```